# Convert Oracle LISTAGG to MsSqlServer construction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to convert this construction from oracle syntaxis to mssql.

```
SELECT
   cs.id,
   LISTAGG(w.WonderNumber, '|')
      WITHIN GROUP (
        ORDER BY w.WonderNumber) AS Wonder
FROM
   CasaS cs
```

I have tried approaches with `FOR XML PATH` but didn't completely understand this. Could you please show solution with explanations. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add sample data  here